# Angular2 rc1 ngFor "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, iterable

I don't have idea how I can iteratem by my object of objects (but it should be array):
[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xorR.png)

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

View structure:

```
  <a *ngFor="let msg of messages " href class="clearfix">
          <div class="img-area"><img [ngClass]="{'photo-msg-item': !msg.from}"
                                     src="{{ ( msg.from ||  (msg.from | baProfilePicture)) }}"></div>
          <div class="msg-area">
            <div>{{ msg.message }}</div>
            <span>{{ msg.send_date }}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
```

Component:

```
 public notifications:Array<Object>;
  public messages:Array<Message>;
  public data_error: Boolean = false;
  constructor(private _baMsgCenterService:BaMsgCenterService) {
      this.messages = this._baMsgCenterService.getMessages().subscribe(
        (messagess) => { 

          let result:Array<Message> = [];
          if (messagess) {
          messagess.forEach((message) => {
            result.push(
               new Message(message[0], 
                        message[1],
                        message[2],
                        message[3],
                        message[4])
               );
          });
        }
        this.messages = result;
        },
      err => { this.data_error = true}
    );
```

Comment: could you post your data that is iterable , also where you get the error line no. ? better if you provide plunker of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is located at this line:

```
this.messages = this._baMsgCenterService.getMessages().subscribe(
```

It seems you're trying to set `Subscription` object to your `messages` variable (`subscribe` method returns `Subscription` object https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L87)

So you have to remove this side effect. It should be:

```
this._baMsgCenterService.getMessages().subscribe(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a *ngFor="let msg of messages | async " href class="clearfix">
```

Try adding some "async"

See [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).